# Error when running worldserver: " 000.vmtree' is missing or points to wrong version of vmap file. Redo vmaps with latest version of vmap_assembler.exe

Tags: azerothcore

When trying to run the `worldserver`, I received the titular error:

```
VMap file 'C:\Users\Christopher\Desktop\MyServer\bin\Debug\data/vmaps/000.vmtree' is missing or points to wrong version of vmap file. Redo vmaps with latest version of vmap_assembler.exe.
```

I have double checked that the `DataDir` parameter in the `worldserver.conf` points to the data folder, here it is below:

```
DataDir = "C:\Users\Christopher\Desktop\MyServer\bin\Debug\data"
```

Edit: I have tried swapping the `\`  for `/` however this made no difference, so I reverted them back to `\`

Comment: That happened to me on linux, and the reason was that I didn't point to the right path :D. I am sure that it is a similar issue, the worldserver doesn't find the maps, it's not a version issue

Comment: But would you say that my pointer is incorrect? It seems to be good to me, which is why im confused about it

Comment: `DataDir = "/home/server/binaries/yhool/dev_realm_1/data"` for me. Also if you look at the error file, it contains both / and \ in the path mentioned. And verify that 000.vmtree exists

Answer (score 3):

Just extract the vmaps from your client, It's always better to generate your data files (From your own client) instead of downloading them from somewhere

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issue by extracting `vmaps` from my own client rather than using the downloads available on the Azerothcore website. I did not change the `Datadir` parameter, so can confirm that it was correct.

I believe this points to a version mismatch for the `000.vmtree`